# Is it possible to create nested namespaces? (so to speak)

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, namespaces

I have a class with many, many (not shared) methods. I'd like to organize them into subcategories so that for example, instead of calling

```
(my class instance).BuildingComponentDoorCreate
```

I could call

```
(my class instance).Building.Component.Door.Create
```

since there are other components besides a door and door specific stuff has other methods than create and so on.

I'm building the class as a sort of framework and right now it just feels very crowded to use. Also, I'd rather not create separate classes for "building" and the components inside the building since it would just add unnecessary complications.

Comment: Unnecessary complication or not it sounds like `Door` should be a class in its own right. This can exist in the `Building.Component` namespace if you wish

Comment: I think `(my class instance)` does a wee bit too much. You can use nested inner classes to use the same syntax but... if you're dealing with other objects they should be their own classes organized within a namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the exact wording of your question, the answer is "no."

If you have a variable `x` that is an instance of a class, and you want to write `x.<something>` in your code, the `<something>` has to be a property or public field.

If you can allow for brackets then you could also have methods, e.g. `x.Something()`. This could be a method declared on the class itself, or an extension method from another `static` class.

Under no circumstances can the `.<something>` following your class instance be a namespace.

You say that your class is crowded; that suggests that you *should* consider creating more classes to better separate your functionality. It's also the only way that you'll be able to organise them in the way you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Use inner classes, which is class inside the existing class.

I have found unless you already have your infrastructure organized in this manner and a useful need to separate  into components it can be more work then it is worth if you already have everything inside a master class.

To go 4 levels deep is also a very large separation of items but the subclassing will inevitably make your code more readable and organized. so it really is a judgment call on your part if you are going to do it.